# dijit.Tree with dojo.store.JsonRest Deleting Items

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've been following this [tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/store_driven_tree/) in regards to connecting a store to a tree all of what is detailed in the tutorial works fine. But I can't figure out how to delete an entry from the tree. Using store.remove (itemid) does trigger the call to DELETE and works fine, but it does not update the tree after the DELETE event has occurred. I've had a look around and seem to be unable to find any working solution for doing this. If some one can spread some light on it I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that you are handling the remove notification in your store

```
remove: function(id){
                this.onDelete({id: id}); 
                return JsonRest.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
            }
```

this is necessary to update the tree after delete REST service is done.